# Excel on Converting Data into Chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I get the Average Score of the same Employee Name with the same month in excel and make it as column chart?

For example :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this are Pivot Tables/Charts.

> - In ribbon Insert>Pivot Chart:
>     [image: Select Table]
> - Toggle Employee, Score, Months
>
> [image: Toggle]
>
> - Set Score to average
>
> [image]
>   [image]
>
> - Review statistics!
>
> [image: Example:]

Comment: Great mate, Thanks for this awesome instructions.